# Open, closed, bounded or sequentially compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

How do I find if this set is open, closed, bounded or sequentially compact?
$$S=\left\{z:5<\left|z\right|\leq7\right\}$$
I find the value of $z$ is: $-7\le z < 0$.
Can you please explain. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

First: The region you are considering is a (geometrical) ring with inner radius 5 and outer radius 7.

Now you see straight away that it the region is bounded since one can find an $M>0$ such that $|z|< M,\ \forall z\in S$... $8$ will do for this specific case.

Now you'll notice that the lower bound is **strict** hence the region is **NOT** closed, and since the upper bound is non-strict it's **NOT** open either.

Hence definitely **NOT** compact (which is equivalent to *closed* and *bounded*)

And at last the region is **NOT** sequentially compact since on metric spaces (where you are in this occasion) sequentially compact is equivalent to compact (see Wiki)

Comment: Thank you for the help i understood but why is it not open? and if there is imaginary and real number in it how do I know if it is open,close,bounded or sequentially compact?

Comment: **If** it would be open then for any point $z_0\in S$ you should be able to build a ball $B_\epsilon(z_0)\subset S, \ \epsilon>0$. The problem is that if you take any $|z_0|=7$ (on the outer border) and try to construct a Ball with center on that point, you will always end up outside of your set, which contradicts the openess. Furthermore we know that the modulus maps $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ hence It would make nop sense at all to put an "imaginary boundary". Conversely one could write something like $\Im(z)>r$ and then you would treat it like done above... Everything clear now? :)